# Assign variable to 'key':value based on value in another key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looping through a dictionary:

```
d = {'clubs': [{'id': 30, 'club_name': 'One'}, 
           {'id': 33, 'club_name': 'Two'}]
    }
```

and assigning the value for the key 'id' to a variable x.

```
for x in d['clubs']:
        x = x['id']
        print(x)
```

I then pass the 'id' to an API call that returns another set of data which will be written to a .csv file. So far so good.

As I loop through, I would like to set another variable to the value in the 'club_name' key of the same record so that I can use it in naming the output file.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just don't name the id variable `x` but something else, so that the loop variable is still visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So something like this possibly:

```
for k,v in d.items():
   if k == "clubs":
      for key,val in d[k].items():
        if key == "club_name":
          getClubVals = d[key]
          # this should be some guidance with what you need, you will get the 
          # values for that specific key i.e "club_name"
          # you can append the values or some do some sort of return with the values
```